# Using SQL Server memory optimized table with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2014

I'm going to use memory optimized table for loading large amount of data in memory. in addition I wanna use entity framework as ORM. I just want to know while memory optimized tables doesn't support identity columns how can I simulate auto increment column using entity framework?